# How to reverse the order of integration in the iterated integral?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, solution-verification

How to reverse the order of integration in the iterated integral
$$
\int_0^1 \int_0^{ \sqrt{2-2x^2} } f(x, y) dy dx? \tag{0} 
$$

My Attempt:

> Here we have
> $$
> 0 \leq x \leq 1, \tag{1} 
> $$
> and
> $$
> 0 \leq y \leq \sqrt{ 2-2x^2}. \tag{2} 
> $$

> Now from (2) upon squaring all the quantities we obtain
> $$
> 0 \leq y^2 \leq 2-2x^2, 
> $$
> which implies
> $$
> 2x^2 \leq 2-y^2,
> $$
> which in fact is
> $$
> 0 \leq 2x^2 \leq 2 - y^2,
> $$
> and hence
> $$
> 0 \leq x^2 \leq \frac{2-y^2}{2},
> $$
> which implies
> $$
> 0 \leq \lvert x \rvert \leq \sqrt{ \frac{2-y^2}{2} }. \tag{3}
> $$

> But from (1) we have $x \geq 0$. So (3) yields
> $$
> 0 \leq x \leq \sqrt{ \frac{2-y^2}{2} }. \tag{4}
> $$

> As $x$ increases from $0$ to $1$ as per (1) above, the quantity $2-2x^2$ decreases from $2$ to $0$ and thus the quantity $\sqrt{ 2-2x^2}$ decreases from $\sqrt{2}$ to $0$, which show that $y$ decreases from $\sqrt{2}$ to $0$.

> Thus from (4) above and the discussion in the preceding paragraph we can conclude that the integral (0) takes the form
> $$
> \int_{\sqrt{2}}^{0} \int_0^{\sqrt{  \frac{2-y^2}{2} } } f(x, y) dx dy. 
> $$

Is what I have done correct and clear enough? Or, are there problems in my procedure?

Answer (score 1):

You are almost right but the final answer is $$
\int_0^{\sqrt{2}} \int_0^{\sqrt{  \frac{2-y^2}{2} } } f(x, y) dx dy. 
$$ instead of  $$
\int_{\sqrt{2}}^{0} \int_0^{\sqrt{  \frac{2-y^2}{2} } } f(x, y) dx dy.  $$

Note that if $f \equiv 1$ then your answer would be negative whereas the given integral is positive.

Comment: apart from the reason you've given, is there any other conclusive rule of thumb to follow in such situations? I've just figured out this same reason, but with $f(x, y) = 4x$.